# A debugger has been found running in your system

Tags: ida, debugging, anti-debugging

For education reasons I just came into reverse engineering, so I found an app that I want to reverse. Basically it has a basic auth system (login and pass). I sniffed traffic with Wireshark and found the packets are encrypted. So i started to reverse engineer it. I tried Ollydbg and IDApro with stealth plugins but still can't run it with debugger. Here is a message when I try to run it with debugger:

```
A debugger has been found running in you system
Please unload it from memory and restart your computer
```

I suppose it is a some lib to prevent debugging because it a pretty standard message because when I try to google it, it appears not only in this program.

So I dive into code. At this moment i found only this 2 functions:

```
.vmp1:013F9BDC loc_13F9BDC:                            ; CODE XREF: sub_1427AA5+4j
.vmp1:013F9BDC                 not     dl
.vmp1:013F9BDE                 bt      ebx, 1Eh
.vmp1:013F9BE2                 rol     dl, 3
.vmp1:013F9BE5                 call    loc_144B5CD
.vmp1:013F9BEA                 and     al, 14h
.vmp1:013F9BEC                 xor     al, 0C3h
.vmp1:013F9BEE                 lodsb
.vmp1:013F9BEF                 cmp     al, 0EAh
.vmp1:013F9BF1                 imul    ebx
.vmp1:013F9BF3                 add     [eax-36h], edx
.vmp1:013F9BF6                 mov     dh, 0DFh
.vmp1:013F9BF8                 sub     ch, [eax]
.vmp1:013F9BFA                 test    al, dh
.vmp1:013F9BFC                 wait
.vmp1:013F9BFD                 adc     esi, 28h
.vmp1:013F9C00                 int     3               ; Trap to Debugger
.vmp1:013F9C01                 sub     ah, bh
.vmp1:013F9C03                 shr     byte ptr [ecx], 1
.vmp1:013F9C05                 jmp     far ptr 0F03Dh:0AE62FB1Fh

    loc_1402816:                            ; CODE XREF: sub_15E0009-1DD80Ej
.vmp1:01402816                 pop     ebp
.vmp1:01402817                 arpl    [ebx], cx
.vmp1:0140281A                 adc     al, 0C8h
.vmp1:0140281C                 int     3               ; Trap to Debugger
.vmp1:0140281D                 sbb     al, 0B2h
.vmp1:0140281F                 loopne  loc_140285A
.vmp1:01402821                 or      al, 0CFh
.vmp1:01402823                 fisttp  qword ptr [edi]
.vmp1:01402825                 xchg    eax, edx
.vmp1:01402826                 sbb     ah, 7Fh
.vmp1:01402829                 retf
.vmp1:01402829 ; END OF FUNCTION CHUNK FOR sub_15E0009
.vmp1:01402829 ; -----------------------------------------------------------------
.vmp1:0140282A                 dw 0BB70h
.vmp1:0140282C                 dd 2FEC5FA0h, 1C84B195h, 0E7C1879Fh, 0F4D8BCF8h
.vmp1:0140283C ; -----------------------------------------------------------------
.vmp1:0140283C                 push    ds
.vmp1:0140283D ; START OF FUNCTION CHUNK FOR sub_15E0009
```

I also tried to undefine those or define as nop. I'm pretty new to reversing and I know only basic of Assembler but have background with C or C++ and some other languages. How can I avoid this anti-debugging ? Maybe some specific settings of a plugin ? Or maybe using another debugger ? Right now I'm trying to use Windbg and win 32 debugger. Or please tell me where to dig. here is DIA output.[image]

Comment: This seems like VMProtect. If you're as new as you're saying, you're "not even close" to getting past this. You need a lot of experience to be able to unpack this packer / virtualizer.

Comment: @AcidShout  . Thank you very much. Can u plz give me a common way to fight this)?

Comment: You can try using Phant0m or StrongOD, or some custom OllyDBG to prevent the debugger detection

Comment: @AcidShout i found a plugin called VMsweeper . Is it the thing  need?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, I never used it. There are prepared OllyDBG editions that are specifically made to evade VMProtect though.

Comment: @AcidShout just try Phant0m and StrondOD with standart  settings.still same message

Comment: Run Die(https://tuts4you.com/download.php?view.3518) and post result here. Depend on it there might be some ways from "possible" to "now way"

Comment: @seeya did it , thx

Comment: @Notevenclose , as you can see, executable is packed with not easiest-to-unpack VMProtect(my fault that I did not guess it from your attached disasm). The fact, that DiE failed to lookup packer version leads me to conclude, that this might be VMP > 2.10 or maybe even newer version.
Check out this RE search query 'VMProtect' just for start, if you're ready to work until it would done. Also I can share unpacking tutorial(unfortunately, in russian) of 2.12 if you're interested - drop me a line.